# Need to write javascript for invoking external REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, api, oauth, appery.io

I am a beginner at javascript and all of the programming :P

I am currently trying to develop an application on appery.io to reconcile data from ecommerce websites for sellers; its pretty cool though and I have planned and understood most of it.

it gives me an option to directly write a javascript and import data.

I am trying to integrate my first portal that is flipkart.com

As per https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs I understand I will have to pass an access token in my request URLs. The hard part I am finding to do or rather stuck at is authenticating myself and get this "authorization token"

as per

https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/FMSAPI.html

I don't know where to pass my app_id and app_secret for request of "Client Credential Flow"

I have written a rather simple code

```
var grant = request.get('grant');
var scope = request.get('scope');
var url = "https://api.flipkart.net/oauth-service/oauth/token"; // REST API URL

var XHRResponse = XHR2.send("GET", url, {
  "parameters": {
    "grant_type": grant,
    "scope": scope,


  }
});
```

where you can assume the grant_type and scope variables to be "client_credentials" and "Seller_api" respectively.

the error the above code returns is

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"
}
```

I also tried authorization code flow but could not make sense of client_id

Any guidance is much appreciated. I hope i made sense.

Regards

Manak

Answer (score 0):

check this one

var XHRResponse = XHR2.send("GET", url, {

"parameters": {
    "grant_type": grant,
    "scope": scope,
"username" :xyz,
password:xyz
  }

Comment: I am sorry; I did not get you; beginner here sir, I dont see an authentication tag

Comment: as per https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/FMSAPI.html I need to pass my app_id and app_secret somewhere to get a token which I can store and pass to get other data.
really appreciate your response

Comment: grant_type: 'grant',
    username: credentials.name,
    password: credentials.password
send username and password also

Comment: still did not get it m sorry; would it be too much to edit the above code? :)